# Can File Sharing being Controlled by Mac Address?

Tags: network, windows, file-system, authorization

I am currently setting up secure environment between 2 pc in isolated network.

Just wondering can we do file sharing based on that pc mac address instead of username?

The environment is OEM Windows 7

Comment: Hi..How are these PCs networked ? (wireless or ethernet)

Comment: Hi aRun, Is connected through Ethernet and using direct straight network cable with static IP address. Any Idea?

Comment: Hi @Kay, welcome to [security.se]. Please read the [FAQ] - questions here must be about security, and not how to configure something. However, instead of just migrating this to [su], can you give us some more information? Some context, as to why you want to do this, from a security PoV. Perhaps your question should be "Is this even a good idea". (The answer would probably be "No.").

Comment: It is worth noting that you would still need usernames.  MAC addresses are not a security measure and can be easily spoofed.  They do not provide authentication.

Answer (score 1):

[MAC addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) resides in Layer 2 of the OSI model. Most of [file sharing protocols are way up in Layer 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_network_protocols_%28OSI_model%29#Layer_7_protocols_.28Application_Layer.29). I doubt you can do what you're trying to do only using MAC addresses.

It *is* possible to transfer *anything* using any layer of the OSI model. You can [get physical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_network_protocols_%28OSI_model%29#Layer_1.2B2_protocols_.28Physical.29) and send the files bit by bit by yourself through the wire. You can even write an [application that uses ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICMP_tunnel) to setup a connection channels and use it to send and receive files.

I'm not sure what this has to do with security, but the answer is yes, it's possible. But I don't think there's any application that readily supports it.

Comment: Don't you want to mention how trivial it is to spoof MAC addresses...?

Comment: @AviD I believe it's not relevant to this question. The OP's network is only between 2 machines in an isolated network. Even "spoofing" IP address in his case would be as easy as going to the Control Panel and writing a new IP address in the TCP/IP settings.

Comment: Hmm, 2 machines in peer-to-peer? So it would be as simple as restricting it as "local" or "not local"... Again why bother with MAC?

Comment: @AviD Exactly my thought. OP didn't give enough information to assess the whole case.